# JQuery Script Issue: x in search field on load or on 'back' button

Tags: jquery

I have a great script for adding an 'x' to the search box. It works if I'm typing something in from scratch, but if text already exists (like clicking back after viewing search results), the 'x' is not present. Any ideas?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/internetjason/LV5hy/)**

```
<input type="search" class="clearable" value="Some search text" placeholder="Search">
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {

    function tog(v) {
        return v ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
    }

    $(document).on('input', '.clearable', function () {
        $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
    }).on('mousemove', '.x', function (e) {
        $(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth - 18 < e.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');
    }).on('click', '.onX', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('');
    });

});
</script>
<style>
.clearable {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/z7ZSYjt.png) no-repeat right -10px center;
    padding:3px 18px 3px 4px;
    border-radius:3px;
    transition: background 0.4s;
}
.clearable.x {
    background-position: right 5px center;
}
.clearable.onX {
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try hover, instead of mousemove?

```
function tog(v) {
        return v ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
    }

    $(document).on('input', '.clearable', function () {
        $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
    }).on('hover', '.x', function (e) {
        $(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth - 18 < e.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');
    }).on('click', '.onX', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('');
    });

});
```

Comment: That actually breaks the functionality. The 'x' is no longer clickable. It also does not show up upon load.